# How to prevent automatic horizontal scroll on cell-click in grid panel

Tags: extjs, extjs6-classic

I have a gridpanel with a very wide column using a custom renderer. The column need to be this wide.

Sometimes the user wants to scroll to the right and click elements in the rightmost part of the cell, which is normally outside the screen/view.

When clicking the cell the grid will automatically make a horizontal scrolling so that the left end of the column becomes visible. I don't want this automatic horizontal scroll to happen. I want the grid to stay where it is seeing only the rightmost part of the column.

Is there a way to prevent the automatic scrolling behavior?

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to set cellFocusable to false on the column.